# Dynamic TypeScript Typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Is there any way to have dynamic object properties in a TypeScript class, and add dynamic Typings in for TypeScript?

I have seen similar questions but none with a complete example like this -

```
interface IHasObjectName {
   objectName: string;
}

class example<A extends IHasObjectName, B  extends IHasObjectName> {

    constructor(a: A, b: B) {
        this[a.objectName] = function() { return a; };
        this[b.objectName] = function() { return b; }
    }
}

class Cat implements IHasObjectName {
    objectName: string = "";
}

class Dog implements IHasObjectName {
    objectName: string = "";
}

let cat = new Cat();
cat.objectName = "Cat";

let dog = new Dog();
dog.objectName = "Dog";

let test = new example<Cat,Dog>(cat, dog);

// ??? TYPESCRIPT DOESN'T KNOW ABOUT THESE DYNAMIC PROPERTIES
// HOW DO I MAKE THIS WORK?
let d = test.Dog();
let c = test.Cat();

// I know I could access like this 
// let d = test["Dog"](); 
// but I want to access like function and have it typed
```

Comment: I have a feeling that we are missing your real use-case here. Is this code really representative for what you want to do? Are you just using dynamic object properties in this example as a way to achieve what you really want, or is dynamic properties really your main interest here?

Comment: You could just use Javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a factory function and [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
function factory<A extends IHasObjectName, B extends IHasObjectName, C>(a: A, b: B): example<A, B> & C {
    return new example<Cat, Dog>(a, b) as C;
}
var test = factory<Cat, Dog, { Dog(): Dog, Cat(): Cat }>(cat, dog);

var d = test.Dog(); // no error
var c = test.Cat(); // no error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IHasObjectName%20%7B%0A%20%20%20objectName%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20example%3CA%20extends%20IHasObjectName%2C%20B%20%20extends%20IHasObjectName%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Ba.objectName%5D%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%20return%20a%3B%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bb.objectName%5D%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%20return%20b%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Cat%20implements%20IHasObjectName%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20objectName%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Dog%20implements%20IHasObjectName%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20objectName%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20cat%20%3D%20new%20Cat()%3B%0Acat.objectName%20%3D%20%22Cat%22%3B%0A%0Avar%20dog%20%3D%20new%20Dog()%3B%0Adog.objectName%20%3D%20%22Dog%22%3B%0A%0A%0Afunction%20factory%3CA%20extends%20IHasObjectName%2C%20B%20extends%20IHasObjectName%2C%20C%3E(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20B)%3A%20example%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%26%20C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20example%3CCat%2C%20Dog%3E(a%2C%20b)%20as%20C%3B%0A%7D%0Avar%20test%20%3D%20factory%3CCat%2C%20Dog%2C%20%7B%20Dog()%3A%20Dog%2C%20Cat()%3A%20Cat%20%7D%3E(cat%2C%20dog)%3B%0A%0Avar%20d%20%3D%20test.Dog()%3B%0Avar%20c%20%3D%20test.Cat()%3B))

---

#### Edit

You can't "reflect" types because they don't exist in runtime, but you can use the `constructor.name` of the passed in instances, so you can simply do this:

```
class example<A, B> {
    constructor(a: A, b: B) {
        this[a.constructor.name] = function() { return a; };
        this[b.constructor.name] = function() { return b; }
    }
}

class Cat {}

class Dog {}

var cat = new Cat();
var dog = new Dog();


function factory<A, B, C>(a: A, b: B): example<A, B> & C {
    return new example<Cat, Dog>(a, b) as C;
}
var test = factory<Cat, Dog, { Dog(): Dog, Cat(): Cat }>(cat, dog);

var d = test.Dog();
var c = test.Cat();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20example%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Ba.constructor.name%5D%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%20return%20a%3B%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bb.constructor.name%5D%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%20return%20b%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Cat%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Dog%20%7B%7D%0A%0Avar%20cat%20%3D%20new%20Cat()%3B%0Avar%20dog%20%3D%20new%20Dog()%3B%0A%0A%0Afunction%20factory%3CA%2C%20B%2C%20C%3E(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20B)%3A%20example%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%26%20C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20example%3CCat%2C%20Dog%3E(a%2C%20b)%20as%20C%3B%0A%7D%0Avar%20test%20%3D%20factory%3CCat%2C%20Dog%2C%20%7B%20Dog()%3A%20Dog%2C%20Cat()%3A%20Cat%20%7D%3E(cat%2C%20dog)%3B%0A%0Avar%20d%20%3D%20test.Dog()%3B%0Avar%20c%20%3D%20test.Cat()%3B))

Comment: In the factory, use the parameters: `return new example<Cat, Dog>(a, b) as C;` ;)

Comment: That is really cool, I learned something there.  I just wish I could avoid the users of the factory having to basically type the methods when calling the factory ( interface type "C").  My goal is just to have test.Dog appear like magic. Might not be possible.

Comment: @user210757 it's not possible.  You're changing the instance at runtime and the compiler has no way of knowing that at compile time.

Comment: i had to do this `return new example<Cat, Dog>(a, b) as example<A, B> & C;` in my specific code (different than example) to get past compiler errors, not sure why. But I guess that would make any other public methods in original "example" class available as well as "C" interface

Comment: @user210757 makes sense

Comment: could I "reflect" interface C somehow and use that information to create the methods in example rather than using the properties "objectName"?

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: @user210757 and Nitzan, if this is some kind of class/object registry, each use of the factory call demands explicit definition of both types, the resulting union type and then the instances as an argument. And then this can only be used for a register of two classes. Maybe solved the example code, but not very reusable and even longer than just `var test = { Dog: () => dog, Cat: ()=> cat };`. Something feels wrong here.

Comment: @Alex I have no idea what this is for, but I too had to deal with something similar. Your solution doesn't help as it only returns the instances of dog and cat, without the implementation of the `example` class.

Comment: Yeah, but I see little use for that class other than being a wrapper for some data. Seems like a lot of unnecessary indirection and complexity for what could have been exactly what I suggested in the above comment. I'd love some clarifications from the OP.

Comment: His code is just a simpler version of what he wanted to ask about

Comment: Yes I know, and since it seems like he asked a XY-question, I'd say it's even more important to understand what real problem he/she really is trying to solve.

Comment: @Alex - yes it's a simpler form of what I'm trying to accomplish: a generic helper class for database many-to-many relationships. Ex: `let helper = factory.create<Student, Class, StudentClass>(students, classes, studentClasses); /* all params are arrays; StudentClass is m2m linking table*/ helper.setClass(classA); /*now filtered*/ let studentsInClassA = helper.students();`  Without the dynamic object functions I'm trying to make work, I have to resort to something like: `helper.setLeft(classA); let studentsInClassA = helper.rights();`  I could provide a complete example if you want

Comment: @user210757  Honestly, that clarification is like music to my ears. It gives so much better context to what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it to `any` object type if you wan't "JavaScript behavior" in TypeScript.

There are two syntax types, which are equivalent:

```
const d = (<any>test).Dog();
const c = (<any>test).Cat();
```

and

```
const testAny = test as any;
const d = testAny.Dog();
const c = testAny.Cat();
```

the last one was created for support in `tsx` files, where  wouldn't work and is now the recommended way.

There is hardly an other way to do that other than use the indexer, since the properties are dynamic and not typed.

BTW I encourage to use `const` and `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: Thanks, that essentially eliminates my typing benefits though. And intellisense.